# What's the proper way to document falsey/truthy in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

It is a widely used practice in Javascript to test a value for truthiness by implicit boolean conversion, as in `if (value) {...}`. It would make sense to document variables as being interpreted as truthy/falsey. Some suggestions (all of them flawed):

a) `@param {Boolean} arg1 - truthy/falsey` too narrow

b) `@param {undefined|Object|Boolean} arg1` what about 0, ''?

c) `@param {*} arg1 - truthy/falsey`

Comment: Are you not then attempting to document the internal workings of a function?  Should you expect the documentation to change if the code was refactored to be an explicit rather than implicit check?

Comment: If it's a parameter and does nothing else, use `Boolean`. If the `value` is used elsewhere, make sure to use the appropriate type (`…|null`).

Comment: Since all values in JS have a truthy-ness, IMHO you should not add this to your type annotation. Be as specific as possible with your type, if you have no idea what the param would be, use `*` or `object` and then add to its description that it will be cast to a boolean. Or maybe, require a boolean if that's your only use for the parameter.